# Parse.Object.destroyAll. how many request?

Tags: parse-platform, promise

I have a question about the destroyAll function

if I delete a result of a query

```
query.find().then( function(results){
    console.log(results.length + ": delete " + i);
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(results);
    }, function(error){
      console.error("internal error: " + error);
      response.error(error);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

if results is an array of 600 items, requests to server will be 600?

I asked this because the code above is part of a loop and server answered with error code 155.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked [a similar question](https://www.parse.com/questions/number-of-requests) to Parse about `saveAll`:

> You can save two objects in a single call with one of the saveAll methods, but that's also going to count as separate API requests for each object being saved.

`destroyAll` is just like `saveAll` and `fetchAll`, and will count as 600 requests.